# Verifying username and password in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm creating a login connected to SQLite in an Android Studio. I want to proceed to my second activity if the username and the password are correct (Of course both are stored in the database). The users can be added from my admin page, which is working fine. How can I check if the username and the password are stored in database?

**Here is my code so far:**

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.example.schoolapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.se.omapi.Session;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.schoolapp.Admin.DBHelper;
import com.example.schoolapp.Admin.ThirdActivity;
import com.example.schoolapp.Eleve.SecondActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBHelper SchoolAppDB;

    //Initialisation des variables
    private EditText Name;
    private EditText Password;
    private Button Login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Mise en relation des variables a leurs correspondants dans le fichier XML par leur ID
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewName);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                //getting Edit Text values and stores it into string
                String username = Name.getText().toString();
                String password = Password.getText().toString();

                //check authorized user or not

                if (SchoolAppDB.checkUser(username, password)) {
                    Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }

        });

    }
}
```

**DBHelper checkUserLogin method :**

```
public boolean checkUserLogin(String username,String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String Query = "select USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD from USER where USER_NAME='"+ username +"' and USER_PASSWORD='"+ password+"'";
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);//raw query always holds rawQuery(String Query,select args)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I sense some plaintext-storing password here. While this could be an app you make for fun, or for training, don't forget to encrypt those if you plan to deploy your app ..

Comment: @forpas I my bad. I just updated the post.

Comment: @ArthurAttout it's a project for uni.

Comment: Doesn't `checkUserLogin()` work?

Comment: @forpas nope it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

You are likely getting a null-pointer exception as you don't appear to have instantiated **SchoolAppDB**.

I'd suggest changing :-

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to be :-

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
SchoolAppDB = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< assuming the DBHelper constructor only requires the Context.
```

I believe you then want `if (SchoolAppDB.checkUserLogin(username, password)) {` rather than `if (SchoolAppDB.checkUser(username, password)) {`.

## Additional

- Directly placing user inputted data into SQL makes the App open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- Checking a Cursor for null, when the Cursor is returned from an SQliteDatabase method such as **rawQuery**, is useless. The Cursor will never be null, if there are no rows returned it will be empty.

It is inadvisable to place calls to SQLiteDatabase methods in try/catch clauses as a serious issue could be hidden.

- There are convenience methods, for commonly used SQL, that make life easier than using rawQuery and execSQL. They build the underlying SQL, the protect against SQL Injection (rawQuery also does if you use the 2nd parameter to provide a String[] of the arguments to replace **?** placehoders).

As such it is suggested that you consider the following **checkUserLogin** method which utilises the **query** convenience method :-

```
public boolean checkUserLogin(String username,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "USER_NAME=? and USER_PASSWORD=?"; //<<<<<<<<<< ?'s will be replaced according to whereargs on a 1 by 1 basis
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{username,password};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "USER",
            new String[]{"USER_NAME","USER_PASSWORD"},
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,null,null
            );
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
   return count > 0;
}
```